# Using If statements folder and sub folders

Tags: bash, shell

I am struggling to use IF statements.

A directory is passed to the script and that directory (which contains any number of subfolders) will either have `.txt` files in or `.tmp` files in and my ultimate goal is to copy all the `.tmp` files to one folder and and `.txt` files to another.

Currently have:

```
shopt -s nullglob
if [[ -n $(echo *.txt) ]]; then

elif [[ -n $(echo *.tmp) ]]; then

else
    echo "nothing Found"
fi
```

But it doesn't check the sub directories. Is there something missing?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to "check"?

Comment: Please, [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/497297/edit) your question and add your clarifications, including the one you gave as a comment to one of the answers (about moving `.tmp` and `.txt` files to different directories). It will help us in providing more focused and effective answers.

Comment: Could someone still tell me how to change this as i might use it in the future. thank you

Comment: @fra-san but I would still like the answer to what i'm asking so that I have the answer for future use.

Comment: @madmiddle Of course you can keep the original meaning of your question, no need to _change_ it. You should just: add details as edits to your question, and not in comments (you can possibly leave a comment to a specific user, signaling that you updated your question); ask a _new question_, possibly linking to this one if you feel it would provide useful context, if you want to ask something significantly different.

Comment: @fra-san Ah i didn't know I shall update the question tomorrow when my head is clear. Thank you. Do i need to add to the title of what else i have asked for ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to use the `find` command:

```
find "$start_dir" -type f -name '*.txt' -exec cp -t "$txt_destination" '{}' +
find "$start_dir" -type f -name '*.tmp' -exec cp -t "$tmp_destination" '{}' +
```

Comment: that seems logical to me thank you. Can i throw something else into the pot. I need it to ignore files names that have 'test' in the name. would that be something like:

    find "$start_dir" -type f -name '*.txt' -and -not -name '*test*' -exec cp -t "$txt_destination" '{}' +

Comment: compound tests get a little messy because find uses some of the same syntax as the shell, so you need to start escaping (or quoting, like I did in my answer). Try this: `find "$dir" -type f \( -name '*txt' -and ! -name '*test*' \) -exec ...` -- don't forget to read your find(1) man page.

Comment: I couldn't get it to work properly with the -t saying that it was an illegal option for cp. I have got the following to work though:
`find "$start_dir -type f -name '*.txt' -exec cp '{}' "$txt_destination" \;` or
`find "$start_dir" -type f \( -name '*txt' -and ! -name '*test*' \) -exec cp '{}' "$txt_destination" \;` if that makes any difference.

Comment: -t is an option for GNU cp

Comment: @madmiddle Please update your question with ALL the requirements rather than asking followup questions in comments. As long as you are unclear about what your question _really_ is, we are unclear of what your question is. This in turn makes it eligible for closing, as "unclear".

Answer (score 2):

> But it doesn't check the sub directories. Is there something missing?

Well, a normal glob doesn't recurse to subdirectories. Since you're using `shopt`, you're probably using Bash, which supports the `**/` notation for recursive globs, provided you set `shopt -s globstar`. With it set, `**/*.txt` would expand to the all files matching `*.txt` also in subdirectories of the current directory.

Answer (score 1):

ikkachu explained bash can do recursive globbing, but didn't say how.  So, let's show how:

```
shopt -s globstar extglob nullglob
txt_files=(**/!(*test*|*sample*).txt)
if (( ${#txt_files} )); then
    cp -t "${txt_files[@]}" $txt_destination
fi

tmp_files=(**/!(*test*|*sample*).tmp)
if (( ${#tmp_files} )); then
    cp -t "${tmp_files[@]}" $tmp_destination
fi
```

---

zsh has been able to do this for over a decade, if I remember correctly.  If you're using zsh rather than bash:

```
setopt extendedglob
txt_files=( **/*.txt~*(test|sample)*(N.) )
if (( $#txt_files )) cp -t $txt_files $txt_destination

tmp_files=( **/*.tmp~*(test|sample)*(N.) )
if (( $#tmp_files )) cp -t $tmp_files $tmp_destination
```

Or in a more C style:

```
setopt extendedglob nullglob
txt_files=( **/*.txt~*(test|sample)*(.) )
if [[ $#txt_files != 0 ]] {
    cp -t $txt_files $txt_destination
}

tmp_files=( **/*.tmp~*(test|sample)*(.) )
if [[ $#tmp_files != 0 ]] {
    cp -t $tmp_files $tmp_destination
}
```

I didn't forget any quotes there; zsh keeps track of array element boundaries rather than just breaking on spaces.  The semicolons after [[ ]] tests are also optional.

Comment: only just starting out but i've noticed that the script begins with `#!/bin/bash`

Comment: How would i go about writing that in Bash please ?

Comment: Most of them start with #!/bin/bash. zsh may generally be ahead of bash in terms of capability, but bash is always far more popular. That said, it looks like it's pretty close to the point where I could consider using it for my shell in a pinch. It now has autocd, associative arrays, menu completion, and most of the other stuff I use. Of course, there's the learning curve, as it does all of those things differently than I'm used to.

Comment: OK, I think I'm done futzing with doing this in bash now.  And since this is a bash question, even though it wasn't tagged that way, I've put the bash answer first.

Comment: @madmiddle If you have restrictions on the type of shell used, then mention this _in the question_.  Currently, you are writing a `bash` script (which is evident from the use of `shopt`) but you never mention `bash` in the question and you have only tagged the question with [tag:shell].

Comment: @EdGrimm thank you for your time. I shall test in the morning. Though on the directories i have noticed it needs to skip files with 'sample' in as well as i've just noticed some of them in the destination folder. is that doable ?